# manipulating Four arrays in a loop

Tags: javascript, php, html

I created an dynamic adding and removing text boxes, 4 textboxes in a row. Now i want the data in each textbox to be saved into database in one row; but under different attribute. I already tried it with only two textboxes and it works. But  in case of 4 textboxes the data saved in the database is wrong. Every time you press the add textbox button another 4 textboxes will appear and the data in those 4 textboxes will be saved under another row.
Heres my code, please tell me whats wrong.

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {

 $("#append").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var textboxes = $(".textbox").length;
        $(".inc").append("<div class='controls'><input class='textbox form-control' type='text' name='textbox[]'><input class='textbox form-control' type='text' name='box[]' ><input class='textbox form-control' type='text' name='box1[]' ><input class='textbox form-control' type='text' name='box2[]' ><a href='#' class='remove_this btn btn-danger'>remove</a> </div>");
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove_this', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
});
</script>
```

**Html:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method= "POST">
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="inc">
        <div class="controls">
            <button style="margin-left: 50px" class="btn btn-info" type="submit" id="append" name="append">
            Add Textbox</button>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="submit"/> 
</div>
```

PHP:

```
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "lala";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$textboxes = $_POST['textbox'];
$textboxes1 = $_POST['box1'];
$textboxes2 = $_POST['box2'];
$boxes = $_POST['box'];
$x=0;
$a=0;
$z=0;

    foreach ($textboxes as $textbox ) {
 $y=0;
            if($y==$x){
                foreach ($boxes as $box ) {
                    if($z==$y){
                        foreach ($textboxes1 as $box1 ) {

                            if($a==$z){
                                foreach ($textboxes as $box2 ) {
                                    if($y==$x){

                                        $sql = "INSERT into sasa (sasa,sasa1,sasa2,sasa3) values('$textbox','$box','$box1','$box2')";
                                        echo $sql . "<br>";
                                        $q = $conn->query($sql);
                                    }
                                    $x++;
                                    $y++;

                                }
                            }
                            $a++;
                        }
                    }
                    $z++;
                }
            }


    }

}
```

Comment: You might not want to keep two submits, instead, keep one as a button another as submit..

Comment: the first submit is when you want to add new textboxes, the second one is for saving the data into database

Comment: Yes But for a form, a good practice would be to keep a single submit,

Comment: will you show me how? could you help me with this?

Comment: So you want to just take the values of the boxes(which can be dynamic in number) and save them in an row?

Comment: yes. under different attributes but in one row,. and if you add another 4 textbox it will be saved into another row again

Answer (score 1):

> Multiple nested `forEach` are not needed.

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#append").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var textboxes = $(".textbox").length;
    $(".inc").append("<div class='controls'><input class='textbox form-control' type='text' name='textbox[]'><input class='textbox form-control' type='text' name='box[]' ><input class='textbox form-control' type='text' name='box1[]' ><input class='textbox form-control' type='text' name='box2[]' ><a href='#' class='remove_this btn btn-danger'>remove</a> </div>");
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.remove_this', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST">
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="inc">
      <div class="controls">
        <button style="margin-left: 50px" class="btn btn-info" type="submit" id="append" name="append">
          Add Textbox</button>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="submit" value="submit" />
  </div>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "lala";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host; dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $textboxes = $_POST['textbox'];
    $textboxes1 = $_POST['box1'];
    $textboxes2 = $_POST['box2'];
    $boxes = $_POST['box'];
    $x=0;
    $a=0;
    $z=0;
    foreach ($textboxes as $key => $textbox ) {
        $box=$textboxes[$key];
        $box1=$textboxes1[$key];
        $box2=$textboxes2[$key];
        $sql = "INSERT into sasa (sasa,sasa1,sasa2,sasa3) values('$textbox','$box','$box1','$box2')";
        echo $sql . "<br>";
        $q = $conn->query($sql);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Did you find any error in console ? Which submit button is not working ? I have executed this code before posting..

Comment: Happy to help! Kindly [accept and up-vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow) if it has solved the purpose :)

Comment: how to ? im new to this site

Comment: Provided link in my previous comment will help :)

Comment: i want the first one textbox to a type as file for image and i want to save it in the databse with a folder name attached to it cause i put all my images in one folder, so i use blob but i only got errors how to do it since its is array? the folder name is images